# Can I download artifacts built by BuildHive?

Tags: github, download, artifact, buildhive

I have started using the free Jenkins build service on [BuildHive](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/) for one of my GitHub projects. This is also my first try doing anything with Maven. I have succeeded in building my project using this script on BuildHive:

```
cd base_dir
mvn package
```

The build log shows that the resulting JAR has been built. Now I would like to offer the JAR to my project's users as a download artifact because GitHub has discontinued the feature of manually uploading binaries in a separate download section.

- Is there any way I can download an artifact, referencing it by a URL? If so, how do I construct the URL, knowing only the artifact's local path from the build log?
- Alternatively, is there a way in which I can push the artifact to another place by adding a command to my build shell script after `mvn package`? I was thinking of something like a `curl` or `ftpput` commmand.

Comment: For my current project, I use this permanent URL to allow downloads:
https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/job/odoepner/job/typepad/lastStableBuild/ Maven artifact repo support for BuildHive has been requested here:
https://github.com/buildhive/buildhive/issues/19 You could add a "me wants it, too" comment there. :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that would be kinda okay. Actually I have switched to a full CloudBees account (free for open source projects) where I have more options in Jenkins, private Maven repos (public or private), private storage space (were I could e.g. put my FTP credentials so they are not visible to everyone) etc.

Comment: I have switched to travis-ci with ftp upload of artifacts:
https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2015/02/15/build-java-maven-github-project-on-travis-ci/

They support encyption of credentials so no need to worry about passwords in build logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I was able to come up with as a quick workaround was to upload the artifacts in question to my FTP server via *curl*, as suggested by my original question. It works, but the downside are the FTP credentials in the build public log. I have counterbalanced that by a shell script on my DSL router which checks for FTP storage abuse every few minutes.

As an alternative I found that after creating a free CloudBees account for my little open source project, I got my own Jenkins build configuration as well as my own artifact repository where to deploy my build artifacts. This is much more elegant and does not involve posting any FTP credentials to a public server.

I am still open for BuildHive-only solutions if anyone has a smart idea. `:-)`